# WooCommerce show "used for variations" tickbox (custom product type)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have created a Custom Variable Product Type named vp_extended. By default the tickbox "Used for variations" is not showing under attributes when I added a attribute named "Size". So when I added below code:

```
<?php
function producttype_custom_js() {

    if ( 'product' != get_post_type() ) :
        return;
    endif;
?>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
       jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

            $('.enable_variation').addClass('show_if_vp_extended').show();

      });
   </script>
<?php 
} 
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'producttype_custom_js' );
```

The tickbox is showing and I can use it. The problem is that when I choose to add another attribute (ex. Gender) the page is loading for a bit then both attributes is missing the tickbox "used for variations".

When I inspect the element in CSS, I can see that my class "show_if_vp_extended" *is* added to the ".enable_variation" class on the *first* element and style says display = block (all good here). But when I add the second attribute to the product it will not get my class *and* the first element change CSS to "display: none" but still having my vp-extended class.

What do I miss or do wrong here?

Picture when JavaScript function works on 1 attribute:
[image: Picture when JavaScript function works on 1 attribute]

Picture when choosing to add 1 more attribute:
[image: Picture when choosing to add 1 more attribute...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newly added attribute isn't in the DOM so your code will not effect it. I believe you need to run your code every time an attribute is added.

Something like this might work:

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'woocommerce_added_attribute', function( event ){
    $('.woocommerce_attribute_data .enable_variation').addClass('show_if_vp_extended').show();
});
```

Or borrowing heavily from Subscriptions, this might be more complete:

```
$('body').on('woocommerce_added_attribute', function(){
    if ($('select#product-type').val()=='vp_extended') {

        $( 'input#_downloadable' ).prop( 'checked', false );
        $( 'input#_virtual' ).removeAttr( 'checked' );

        $('.show_if_variable').show();
        $('.hide_if_variable').hide();
        $('.show_if_vp_extended').show();
        $('.hide_if_vp_extended').hide();
        $( 'input#_manage_stock' ).change();

    }
});
```

Comment: Marked as correct. The first snippet works out of the box, have not tried the second one. Your are a god!

Comment: @saveATcode I don't see how your commented is related to this answer or the OP's question. If you have your own question you should post it separately.